# How do I make sure that text following a collapsible table displays below it, and not to the right?

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

The text following a left-justified, narrowed (width:70% ) collapsing table is displaying to the right of the table. I can't get it to move below it.

I've tried placing `<br/>` after the collapsing table as well as inside (which obviously just puts a break within a cell). Removing the left-alignment fixes this problem, but creates another where the table edges narrow to the minimum height.

Here's the code, written in MediaWiki's syntax (hence the braces and pipes). It still uses HTML and CSS, just formatted a bit different:

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" align="left" style="display:inline; width:70%; text-align:left; background:#f9f9f9; border:1px #0a0a0a solid; border-radius: 10px;"
! Header text here. Just after it to the right goes the button.
|-
| Body content goes here. Intended to be a long list of items, only using the one cell.
It could be paragraphs. Maybe it's a poem.
It uses multiple lines to say what it needs to say.

Table width narrowed to 70% to make the problem obvious, btw. Actual value will be 95%.
|}
<br/>

This paragraph comes after the collapsible table.
```

The result I hope for is that from the start, the table header shows with a button for expanding the table. There's a paragraph below the table, and it stays below the table when it expands.

Instead, the following paragraph starts immediately to the right of the narrowed table. Adding any line breaks `<br/>` after the table code doesn't do anything but move the paragraph down by one line. (Presumably that line break is ending up to the right of the table as well.)

Comment: In HTML5 the official way to do this is to style the following paragraph with `clear:both`.  Historically `<br clear="all" />` would have had the desired effect but attributes on `<br/>` have been declared obsolete in HTML5.

Comment: Would you use `<div clear:both>` straight after it then?

Comment: To apply a style from within the definition of the element, use the `style` attribute. It would be `<div style="clear:both">`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<div style="clear:both">` afterward fixes the problem:

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" align="left" style="display:inline; width:70%; text-align:left; background:#f9f9f9; border:1px #0a0a0a solid; border-radius: 10px;"
! Header text here. Just after it to the right goes the button.
|-
| Body content goes here. Intended to be a long list of items, only using the one cell.
It could be paragraphs. Maybe it's a poem.
It uses multiple lines to say what it needs to say.

Table width narrowed to 70% to make the problem obvious, btw. Actual value will be 95%.
|}

<div style="clear:both"></div>

This paragraph comes after the collapsible table.
```

The paragraph can also be inside the `<div>`:

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" align="left" style="display:inline; width:70%; text-align:left; background:#f9f9f9; border:1px #0a0a0a solid; border-radius: 10px;"
! Header text here. Just after it to the right goes the button.
|-
| Body content goes here. Intended to be a long list of items, only using the one cell.
It could be paragraphs. Maybe it's a poem.
It uses multiple lines to say what it needs to say.

Table width narrowed to 70% to make the problem obvious, btw. Actual value will be 95%.
|}

<div style="clear:both">
This paragraph comes after the collapsible table.
</div>
```